# Wake on Phy on Asus P5Q running Ubuntu Server not working

Tags: networking, wake-on-lan, ubuntu-server

I´m running a homeserver with Ubuntu Server OS for Backups and media streaming. 
I want to configure it the way that it suspends itself after a period of time with no avitivty and start up again when it is needed. For suspending I am using a script which checks for SSH, samba and other activities. This part of the plan is working, however I´m having trouble configuring the wake-up process.

According to ethtool, my mainboard supports wake on magic packet (g) and wake on physical activity (p). I´d like it to wake up on physical activity, and set everything like it should be, activated wake on lan settings in bios and configured the lan port on my board. 
Now for some reason the server doesnt wake up if anything tries to access it, strangely it can only be reactivated by sending a magic packet, even though I set the lan port to wake up on physical activity and not on a magic packet.

What is going on here? I´m fairly new to Linux, sorry if this is a noob question, but it feels rather strange to me, for my part everything should be working. Maybe there is some configuration file that somehow overwrites my changes?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What would be "physical activity" on the LAN port? Physical activity is typically defined as pressing keys on an attached keyboard or moving an attached mouse.

Comment: As far as I know it means that any package arriving on the LAN port wakes the machine up